What is the best iterator idea for graph-like structures?
I'm implementing a graph structure.
struct Node {
  std::vector<size_t> neighbours;  // returns the index of node in Graph::nodes
  // ... node info
};

class Graph {
  std::vector<Node> nodes;  // adjacency list
};

I want to create a struct with which the user could iterate over Graph. First approach is evident (I do not use std::vector<Node>::iterator because there can be reallocation).
class Iterator {
  size_t id;
  Graph* ptr;  // access via ptr->nodes[id]
};

However, the user may want to std::move(graph) (e.g. std::vector<Graph> reallocation) and then all Iterators are invalidated. Moreover, having raw pointer is considered a bad practice for me.
Question: what is the solution to have some sort of stable Iterators to graph?
I do not want the user to have size_t variable id instead of Iterator, which he would pass to some Graph method (e.g. graph.neighbours(node_id)).
My only idea was to create a box of memory somewhere outside Graph, to store a pointer to the box in Graph and store a pointer to the graph in the box. Then, whenever someone std::moves graph we update box's pointer. And whoever obtains a pointer to the box can always get a current address of graph. So, it looks like this:
class Graph {
  std::vector<Node> nodes;  // adjacency list
  my::Stalker<Graph> self;
};

class Iterator {
  size_t id;
  my::Stalker<Graph>::stalker ptr;  // access via ptr.ref().nodes[id]
};

However, something tells me that I do some overengineering or miss a better solution. I want either a professional solution if such exists or just some critics.

The iterators refer to nodes so there's no reason to invalidate iterators when a graph is moved that I see.

@TedLyngmo do you mean that we can store a pointer in Iterator that would point to std::vector in Graph?

As long as what the iterator refered to is still reachable after the move, there's no inherent reason to destroy that. If you move an unordered_set for example, all iterators to nodes in the old unordered_set (except an end iterator)  will still be valid after the move.

I think it is a solution. But. Is un_set really used in such situations? I doubt that programmers would sacrifice vector speed...

If you sacrifice one indirection by making a pointer to the data (a std::unique_ptr<std::vector<T>> basically), you'd have a fixed initial cost for dereferencing that pointer but the iteration etc. would be just as fast as before. You'd get top-speed moves and no iterator invalidation.

Hmm, you don't actually need an extra pointer when I think of it. Moving a std::vector<T> won't invalidate iterators either. Silly me :-)

do you have any real requirements ?! a perfect tree doesn't exist, the requirement for a stable node pointer is usually satisfied by vector<unique_ptr<Node>> children; or a shared_ptr if you are super worried about safety or each node can have multiple parents, and if allocation becomes a bottleneck you can always use a custom allocator.

Implement a very stupid implementation that works then use that as a starting point to guide you to what needs improvement to satisfy the requirements, otherwise you are just overengineering and chasing ghosts.

The usual solution is for the graph to store it's Nodes in a data structure that doesn't invalidate iterators, like unordered_set or list. Since iterators are never invalidated, then all of these concerns go away.
If you really don't want that, then the next solution is to give each Node some sort of NodeId (which can be a size_t, or anything else, and then the graph has to provide some way of quickly getting a Node by its NodeId. And then you also make a custom iterator that can iterate over the NodeIds, and get the Node for the current NodeId.
If the user std::move(graph), then the iterators should be invalidated, because they refer to a graph that is now empty. If you need the iterators to not be invalidated, then you need to not invalidate the graph.

unordered_set uses list and I believe there are a lot of unneeded calls to new. Also my approach (even with std::shared all over there) should work faster than unordered_set.
Maybe you can say that one of the approaches (un_set or Graph methods with NodeId) is widely used in the industry?

@MilkyWay yes, it does use list, and have a lot of calls to new. Its hard to argue they're unnecessary, because the lack of cache coherency is WHY they don't invalidate iterators. The usual answers are either these node data structures or using some sort of key, or writing code that doesn't rely on iterators being valid around mutations. The only other answer is effectively reinventing a heap. Your "solution" is a complex version of std::unique_ptr<Graph>, which falls under not using iterators between invalidation. It just happens to never invalidate.

The most common solutions are to simply not mutate data structures while they're being iterated. in the cases where threading makes that difficult or impossible, we use locks. in very rare cases, we may replace the lock with a thread safe map or set or very rarely, a thread safe sequential container. I've never had to deal with complex multithreading much in C++, most of my experience with this type of complexity is in Java.
